# Android URLConnection can not find the file with url having special characters hosted at the localhost server

Tags: java, android, url

I am working on an Android app that has an internal localhost server file access mechanism based on java. The files are stored at some destination by that server and are accessed with the
localhost Url. For ex. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_file/coretest/a_test_file.txt.`

This works fine with Files having names without any special characters. but when it has some special characters, then the resulting encoded url throws java.io.FileNotFoundException.

for ex. a file with the name  `android's_file.txt`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_file/coretest/android%27s_file.txt
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
```

Below is the intial code to access the file:

```
 URL url = new URL(strUrl);
 URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
 InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

`Uri.encode` is already applied to the name.

I have already explored similar issues but all points to the encoding the Url with `utf-8` which I have already done as you can see in the resulting Url.

Comment: `then the resulting encoded url throws` Url's dont throw. You should tell who really throws that exception. Your client or your server. Further you should post complete relevant code.

Comment: `Android app's localhost java server can not find the file ..`  Are you sure the server cannot find the requested file? It looks more that okhttp cannot send the data to your server. Please find out and tell us.

Comment: @blackapps, my silly, the words were typed in hurried moments, anyway, I have edited my question and description to be more specific. `It looks more that okhttp cannot send the data to your server.` No data is beign sent as the file is already there on the local server and it is only being accessed.

Comment: You have to check with your internal server: the "FileNotFound" suggests that it sends a 404. Since you didn't tell us how the server works, you'll have to debug that and check why it doesn't find the file.

Comment: `No data is beign sent as the file is already there on the local server ...` Sorry, you understand wrong. Okhttp should send the file name to the server isnt it? That is the data i'm talking about. So is the data sent? Or does the server not know how to handle the data? With data being that encoded file name. I asked that before but you did not react.